# Why do I always have the error message Controller has no attribute is_pressed?

Tags: python, pynput

I've been coding a very simple autoclicker. My autoclicker works just fine, but the only way to kill it is forcefully shut down my computer because it clicks so fast I can't access my taskbar. I could make it slower, but I'd prefer a way for the user to close the autoclicker with the press of a button. I've tried `if keyboard.is_presssed('q'): break` but I always get the error message AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'is_pressed'. Did you mean: 'alt_pressed'? I expected my code to break the loop when I press q, but instead I get an error message. The error message will also pop up without the pressing of q. My code as of now is:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()
mouse = Controller()


while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    mouse.click(Button.left)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
```

Comment: you can't have two objects with the same name `Controller` - second `Controller` replace first `Controller` - you have to use `pynput.mouse.Controller` and `pynput.keyboard.pynput.Cntroller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pynput` doesn't have `is_pressed()` - I don't know where you find it.

You should rather use `pynput.keyboard.Listener` to run code when `q` is pressed and set some variable - `q_is_pressed = True` - or run code which ends program.

---

You can't have two objects with the same name `Controller`.

One `Controller` replaces other `Controller` and later you use the same `Controller` to create `mouse` and `keyboard` - and this makes problem.

You have to use `pynput.mouse.Controller` and `pynput.keyboard.pynput.Controller`

```
import pynput
from pynput.mouse import Button
from pynput.keyboard import Key
import time

keyboard = pynput.keyboard.Controller()
mouse    = pynput.mouse.Controller()

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    mouse.click(Button.left)
    #if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # <-- this will need Listener()
    #    break
```

---

**EDIT:**

To end code when `q` was pressed you have to use `Listener`

For example:

```
import pynput
from pynput.mouse import Button
import time

mouse_controller = pynput.mouse.Controller()

def on_press(key):
    print('pressed:', key)
    if str(key) == "'q'":  # it has to be with `' '` inside `" "`
        # Stop listener
        print("exit listener")
        return False  # `False` ends listener

with pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as keyboard_listener:
    
    while keyboard_listener.is_alive():
        time.sleep(10)
        mouse_controller.click(Button.left)
        print('clicked')
```

Comment: Even after I used your fix I still get the same error message, AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'is_pressed'. Did you mean: 'alt_pressed'?

Comment: as I wrote in first part - `pynput` DOES'T have `is_pressed`. It may need to use `Listener` to catch it. And I'm working on this part.

Comment: I added example which uses `Listener` to detect pressed `q`